# How do I run a method on a schedule in Java EE?

Tags: java, ejb, java-ee-7

tell me how in java ee you can run a method that will work at a certain time, for example at 12 am?
I tried to apply

```
@Lock(LockType.READ)
@Schedule(second = "/1")
public void atSchedule() throws InterruptedException {
//do something
}
```

but it didn't work, besides, I don't understand whether I need to call this method somewhere or the container will launch it itself?